# I want to bulk-edit a domain change for Rod Elliott's Audio Pages

Tags: support, hyperlinks

The excellent [Audio Pages](http://sound-au.com/index.html) by Rod Elliott had to move to a new hosting company, and the URL had to change with the move.

> Despite 18 years of use, Westhost doesn't value their long-term customers, so we will be parting ways.

I'm sure some of you have noticed that I have already updated the previous URL `http://sound.whsites.net` to the new `https://sound-au.com` manually over a few days, trying not to flood the front page. I did this because the automatic redirect will likely disappear in a year or so.

There are however still 87 posts containing the *old*-old URL: `http://sound.westhost.com`. This URL does not redirect anymore, and thus these links are broken but easily repaired by doing a search-and-replace `http://sound.westhost.com` to `https://sound-au.com`. The rest of the URL has not changed.

Is it possible for a diamond-mod to do such changes in bulk, or is there a bot that can do it? Otherwise I will do them manually over the next weeks.

The related "main" meta question [Bulk change hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193591/bulk-change-hyperlinks) tells me that it was not possible as of 2013, but I thought I could ask a more specific question here after 6 years of development, and this also serves as a "heads up" to let people know I'll be changing things.

Comment: That sucks that all the links have changed. I would think a bulk edit moderation system would be like bringing the death star into the world of edits, lots of opportunity for abuse. Bring it up on SE meta, as a feature request. I wouldn't mention the specifics, just plead the case for a bulk edit system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Phew! All done!

[image]

Manually changed every link, and did some very minor cleaning on the respective answers (and sometimes the questions, while they were already bounced to the front page).

Also got me the [*Archaeologist*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/archaeologist) badge:

> Edit 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months.